# How can Ruby on Rails help to embed video to the pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video

Is there any helper (perhaps, an interface to some other video embedding framework) that can be given a filename (of a local file) and would then yield HTML/Flash/something else that shows basic video player?

It shouldn't be an interface to youtube or something like that.  The video should be hosted at the server I'm developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have can check this app http://github.com/balgarath/video-app it may be a starting point to find out what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to contain everything I need.  After I investigate it further, I'll edit your answer or add my one.

Comment: It worked!  I had troubles in converting video, since not should you only change container to "flv" (as implemented there), but also re-encode it to another format (h264 went ok).